# MFC program hangs: broken Comctl32.dll after update KB3059317 on Vista?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, comctl32

I have an MFC-based program which worked fine just before applying update [3059317](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3059317):

> MS15-060: Vulnerability in Microsoft common controls could allow remote code execution: June 9, 2015)

The update replaces `Comctl32.dll` with a new version.

After applying this update, opening a dialog just hangs the program. Not all dialogs seem to be affected, but the print preview is consistently hanging, without crashing the program, though. It just becomes unresponsive.

I've no idea how I could try to debug this problem in order to find a way around it. Creating a memory dump when the program is hung gives following stack trace:

```
comctl32.dll!751f8505() 
Xxx.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2095 + 0x13 bytes
Xxx.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 285
Xxxx.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 434 + 0x10 bytes
user32.dll!76aafd72() 
user32.dll!76aa84de() 
user32.dll!76aafd72() 
user32.dll!76aa9f8d() 
ntdll.dll!77dd5a7e() 
user32.dll!76aaa2af() 
comctl32.dll!75249cfb() 
comctl32.dll!751fb559() 
user32.dll!76aafd72() 
user32.dll!76aafe4a() 
user32.dll!76ab09d3() 
user32.dll!76abb759() 
Xxx.exe!CWnd::DefWindowProcA(unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 1116 + 0x7 bytes
Xxx.exe!CWnd::Default() Line 315 + 0x13 bytes
Xxx.exe!CParsedEdit::OnPaint() Line 1603
Xxx.exe!CBannerEdit::OnPaint() Line 368
```

So we are indeed stuck in `Comctl32.dll` - now what?

By the way, in some cases, uninstalling the update solves the issue.

**UPDATE**

In all cases, turning off Aero always solves the issue. And KB3059317 seems
not to be the only June 2015 update to Windows Vista which exhibits this
weird behaviour.

Comment: Looking at `CWnd::WindowProc` what is `this` pointing to? What are the values of `message`, `wParam` and `lParam`?

Comment: I have a few applications crashing on my system because of that update too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails with Areo Vista at least for one dialog in our app: the dialog is just not painted. It is present, but it is just not visible.

To resolved the problem on Vista Aero, remove any calls to `SetRedraw()` function while executing `OnInitDialog()` and `OnSize()` methods.

It seems that `SetRedraw(TRUE)` has no (positive) effect, at least in these two cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a custom program written in .NET 4 which uses a customized version of the ListView control.  The program doesn't hang it produces and error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.".  After uninstalling this update everything is fine.